# Sum of Rows - SQL query

Tags: sql, netezza

I need to develop a SQL query that does the following:

```
        Column A     Column B

Row1    2861682      sum(Row1 to Row5)
Row2    2522226      sum(Row2 to Row5)  
Row3    2285983      sum(Row3 to Row5)
Row4    2096046      sum(Row4 to Row5)  
Row5    1935355      sum(Row5)
```

This is the data I have in a table column.

Now I need to calculate

```
sum(Row1 to Row5) 
sum(Row2 to Row5) 
sum(Row3 to Row5) 
sum(Row4 to Row5)
sum(Row5)
```

Thanks

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard SQL form for this uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(B)
        from t t2
        where t2.A >= t.A
       ) as TheSum
from t;
```

Some databases also support window/analytic functions that allow cumulative sums.

EDIT:

Netezza is one of the databases that support cumulative sums using window functions (thanks to its Postgres heritage, I imagine).  You can also express this as:

```
select t.*,
       sum(B) over (order by A desc) as TheSum
from t
```

EDIT II:

I don't have a Netezza database to test on, but it does have the `RowId` column.  You might be able to use this, although I cannot find any documentation that guarantees its being monotonically increasing.  In fact, I'm pretty sure that for a parallel load, the rowid would *not* be monotically assigned.

The query would look like:

```
select t.*,
       sum(B) over (order by rowid desc) as TheSum
from t
```

Comment: Can you please explain what t and B represent. B column is represented based on the summation

Comment: @Moonwalk . . . `t` represents your table.  `A` is the first column (seems to contain the values `row1` etc.).  `B` is the second column that seems to contain the value you want to sum.  SQL Tables are inherently unordered (especially on a parallel database system such as Netezza).  If you don't have an identifier for the ordering (such as an id or creation date), then the cumulative sum just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hi Gordon - B is the new column.I have data only for A column . Only B column values are to be calculated.

Comment: @Moonwalk . . . What column do you use to determine what row is first, second, third, and so on?  SQL Tables are inherently unordered, so you need to store this information in a column.

Comment: I thought I can do with a row number? I do not have a primary key column

Comment: @Moonwalk . . . You don't need a primary key.  You need a way of defining order.  Another typical column would be a creation date.